# ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent in service

Tags: android

I am using this code to track battery information in my service:

```
    Intent i = new ContextWrapper(applicationContext).registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
     // now you can get the level and scale from this intent variable
    int level = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float battPct = level/(float)scale;
```

1.I want to know if it will change automatically then battery is changed? Or do I need to fire that intent by myself periodically?
2. Also I would like to know if there is a way to calculate how much time elapsed since 1% of remaining battery has been used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Better way to get change value  you should use `BroadcastReceiver`.

To get changed value when battery change. You need to use `BroadCastReceiver`.

```
IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);

BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        float battPct = level/(float)scale;       
    }
};
```

Comment: It is possible to do it in Service? Because I tried it earlier but it even does not execute log that I inserted in Broadcast receiver. If you could provide some example, I would appreciate.

Comment: @whiteLT You can use debug if log is not working.. and your second question you need to write the code and save the value the time elapsed since 1%.

Comment: Yes, do you know how to implement that "time elapsed calculator"? Do I need to mark one time at beginning and then after `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` just mark again?

And do you really know that this `BroadcastReceiver` will work although in `Service`? It is working in my Activity(showing logs and etc.)

Comment: Maybe you know how can I pass information from service OnReceive to my activity? Because if I try to use information outside OnReceive, I get 0. Example:
`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
.....
 int level = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
a=level;
    }`
And I try to reach a outsite onReceive, I always get 0, why it is impossible to reach it outside OnReceive method?

Answer (score 0):

**Following thing worked for me:**

In manifest file, find `**<activity android:name=".MainActivity">**`
and replace with `***<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">***`